# Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. Xampp

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, xampp

I was getting this error using xampp to run an apache server and wanted to explain how I solved it. The error is pretty self explanatory once you know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

Enable the `intl` extension in the `php.ini` file.

Under Apache, click config.

[image: xampp apache]

Click `php.ini`.

[image: menu]

ctrl + f to search `intl` to find the extension.

[image: extension in file, disabled]

Remove the semi-colon to enable the extension. (This is something that wasn't self explanatory to me at first).

[image: extension in file, enabled]

Save the file. Restart your apache server in xampp. The error should now be resolved.

Comment: It's good that you want to help, but if you google "enable intl extension xampp", you'll find several answers for this already (including questions/answers here in SO). No need for another duplicate.